# What formats does SoundMiner accept to import Metadata?

Tags: metadata, soundminer, importing

I'd like to update my metadata outside of SoundMiner, but I don't know what format it accepts. Is it XML, CSV or something else?

In short: What format does SoundMiner accept to import metadata from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page indicates that the format is a plain text (.txt) file:
http://www.creativefieldrecording.com/2014/06/24/the-power-users-guide-to-soundminer-metadata/

The following excerpt from that page hints that they're formatted as **tab-delimited text**.

> "Ensure there’s a “tab character” between the data in each column.
>   This keeps the data in one column from becoming confused with its
>   brothers on either side."